# Structural Navigation shows a wrong link

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, navigation

I am using SharePoint 2013 on premise. A site administrator moved a subsite to a different site collection in the same web application. However, the link to this subsite is still showing up in the structural navigation of the original site. I tried to manually delete it: go to Site Settings-> Navigation Settings, the link is not shown in the Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting tab.

Is there any way to get rid of that link in the structured navigation? Is it maybe cached? Any help would really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How did you move the subsite from one site collection to another site collection?

And did you delete the subsite in the original site collection?

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Clear IE cache.
2. Reset IE settings. Go to IE->internet options->advanced tab->reset.
3. Switch to other browsers.